# Is it possible to make a funnel chart(highcharts) having equal partions but the data to show in each partition is different?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want a funnel chart to use in angular where I want the funnel to have equal partitions but the data to represent in each partition is different. Is there a way to achieve this?
[I am getting output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUhRH.png)

I want output almost like in the below image[I want it in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xktJ5.png)

**code**
I am using highcharts in an angular project. I have to make the funnel with equal partitions
*

Below is my js code

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'funnel',
       
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Sales funnel'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
                softConnector: true
            },
            center: ['40%', '50%'],
            neckWidth: '30%',
            neckHeight: '0%',
            width: '80%',
          
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
    
        name: 'Unique users',
        data: [
            ['Website visits', 100],
            ['Downloads',20],
            ['Requested price list',40],
            ['Invoice sent',60],
            ['Finalized',30]
        ]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500,
                minHeight:'20%'
               
            },
            chartOptions: {
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            inside: true
                        },
                        center: ['50%', '50%'],
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '20%'
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

Below is the css file

```
#container {
    height: 400px; 
}

.highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 360px; 
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

Below is the html code

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Chart showing a sales funnel. A funnel chart is often used to visualize
        data from stages of a process. Readers can quickly identify bottlenecks
        in the process by comparing the area size variation of each stage.
    </p>
</figure>
```

*If there is a way or any alternate suggestion for this problem, please let me know?

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72183255/8059419